# Specific suggestions on how to prepare for AngularJS 2.0?

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS 1.3 application that will I suppose eventually move to AngularJS 2.0. I've watched the videos from ng-europe and I understand there are many changes. As I expect development to continue with our AngularJS 1.3 code for the next 12 I would like to hear if anyone has any specific suggestions on preparing for 2.0.

My application is simple in that it creates no directives. In particular I would like to hear any tips on how I should go about creating controllers to get ready for them being very different in 2.0. Should I eliminate all references to scope in my controllers. Should I move everything to services?

I hope for some useful suggestions but of course specific ones so this question does not get closed.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can I start doing today to prepare for Angular 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26682705/what-can-i-start-doing-today-to-prepare-for-angular-2-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that so little has specifically been announced yet, and there's so much potential for it to change that it's a hard question to answer, e.g. [check out this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/133) for an example of something quite fundamental that's likely to change since the ng-europe announcement.

Within my team we're trying to take the following approach:

1. Try not to use $scope (controller-as syntax).
2. Keep your controllers as light as possible by using directives to encapsulate UI functionality and services to deal with data models / API calls.
3. Use the [new syntax for one-way binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding) where you don't need two-way binding.  One-way binding will be the default for Angular 2.0.
4. Write some unit tests!  It'll be much easier to do some significant refactoring if you have some confidence that your code will still work :).

Not only should that help with the move to 2.0 if / when that happens, but it should help your 1.3 apps too!